# Node/Express API request proxy error using Cloud 9. How do I solve this?

Tags: node.js, express, proxy

I am working on a simple 'app', and thus, trying to retrieve information from an API (OMDB) but keep getting the following error message:

```
express deprecated res.send(status, body): Use res.status(status).send(body) 
instead app.js:18:10
_http_server.js:193
    throw new RangeError(`Invalid status code: ${statusCode}`);
    ^

RangeError: Invalid status code: 0
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:193:11)
    at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (_http_server.js:158:8)
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.end (_http_outgoing.js:585:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/home/ubuntu/workspace/APIs/movieapp/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:211:10)
    at ServerResponse.json (/home/ubuntu/workspace/APIs/movieapp/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:256:15)
    at ServerResponse.send (/home/ubuntu/workspace/APIs/movieapp/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:158:21)
    at Request._callback (/home/ubuntu/workspace/APIs/movieapp/app.js:18:10)
    at Request.self.callback (/home/ubuntu/workspace/APIs/node_modules/request/request.js:187:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:172:7)
```

I'm on cloud 9, and am just getting my feet wet with regards to NodeJS/Express, so I am a bit lost here. I have tried editing the code as per several suggestions/looking at similar queries but nothing seems to work. The message error message I get on the web page is as follows: ECONNRESET: Request could not be proxied! There was an error proxying the request.

Here's my code:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var request = require("request");

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.send("Welcome to Our Site");
});

app.get("/movie", function(req, res) {
    request('http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Inception', function (error, response, body) {
      if (error) {
        res.send('error:', error);
      }
      else if (Number(response.statusCode) !== 200) {
        res.send('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);
      }
      else {
        res.send('Awards:', JSON.parse(body).Awards);
      }
    }); 
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function(){
   console.log("Server started!!!"); 
});
```

Side note: I tried making the following request and it works:

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Inception', function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) {
    console.log('error:', error);
  }
  else if (Number(response.statusCode) !== 200) {
    console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); 
  }
  else {
    console.log('Awards:', JSON.parse(body).Awards);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res.send([body])`

Sends the HTTP response.

The body parameter can be a Buffer object, a String, an object, or an Array. For example:

```
res.send(new Buffer('whoop'));
res.send({ some: 'json' });
res.send('<p>some html</p>');
res.status(404).send('Sorry, we cannot find that!');
res.status(500).send({ error: 'something blew up' });
```

https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var request = require("request");

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.send("Welcome to Our Site");
});

app.get("/movie", function (req, res) {
    request('http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Inception', function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            res.send({ 'error': error });
        }
        else if (Number(response.statusCode) !== 200) {
            res.send(response).status(response.statusCode)
        }
        else {
            // res.send(JSON.parse(body).Awards);
            res.send({ 'Awards': JSON.parse(body).Awards });
        }
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("Server started!!!");
});
```

In the below code you are just doing console, so it will work fine and just print out the strings and the values

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Inception', function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) {
    console.log('error:', error);
  }
  else if (Number(response.statusCode) !== 200) {
    console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); 
  }
  else {
    console.log('Awards:', JSON.parse(body).Awards);
  }
});
```